# iOS PubNub SDK update PNChannelProtocol.h not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, ios8, pubnub

I am using PubNub iOS SDK and I want to update library. I added PubNub manually (not by cocoapods) so I want to update is manually. I have Libaries folder next to project-ios folder. In there I have PubNub folder with Core, Data and so. I replace old files with new one from PubNub iOS SSK (path: iOS / iPadDemoApp / pubnub / libs / PubNub).

The problem is that now I can't build project because error Not found on line

```
#import "PNChannelProtocol.h"
```

in `PNAccessRightsInformation` class.

File `PNChannelProtocol.h` is in PubNub folder but it is in `Misc/Protocols` and class `PNAccessRightsInformation` is in `Data`

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: I'll ping the PubNub client SDK depot for details on compiling Obj-C after copying new files into the project directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to first delete all existing PubNub files first, then once you have done that, re-add the files to the project, and ensure that all the files are linked.

If this still presents an issue, zip up the project and send it to us at support@pubnub.com so we can take a deeper look.

geremy

Comment: I am still facing the issue , and project file is too big to be sent in Zip.

Comment: Ok i created a sample project which gives me same error. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Utu0Wqg05HZW4yZ3R5aktGRVE/view?usp=sharing   Thanks

Comment: @mihirmehta please contact support@pubnub.com so we can better assist you... then we can post solution here after we've narrowed it down...

Comment: Sent with subject line :  Regarding iOS PubNub SDK in Swift3/Xcode 8 ... Also attached Sample Code.